# Compare viewport and screen size on mobile displays

Tags: android, css, mobile, viewport

As I've understood it, there are two supposedly reliable methods of determining the viewport width and the screen width on mobile displays. The viewport width is the virtual pixels, and screen width is the physical pixels. That's how it's supposed to be. But it's all the same for me. I've tested the following page with Android 4.0.4's stock browser and Chrome for Android in its current version (it won't tell me its number).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="info"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function () {
    var virtualWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var physicalWidth = screen.availWidth;

    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =
        'Virtual width: ' + virtualWidth + '<br>' +
        'Physical width: ' + physicalWidth + '<br>' +
        'Ratio: ' + (physicalWidth / virtualWidth);
}, 500);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the results:

The stock browser reports 540 for both values, Chrome reports 360 for both. The ratio is always 1. My phone is a Motorola RAZR i, and it should have a physical width of something around 540 (portrait orientation) and a ratio of 1.5. What's wrong with this page or the method, or the browsers? It's really hard to do mobile webdesign if the tools are totally unreliable. (And I'm not yet speaking of the random text size in Chrome...)

Update: Here's a [live URL](http://unclassified.de/tmp/ratio.html) for you to do your own testing. Get a [QR code](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=480x480&chl=http://unclassified.de/tmp/ratio.html) of it.

Comment: Is there a practical application for this question?

Comment: I'm currently using device-dpi for my design, but then I need to handle all sorts of resolutions to manually set a readable text size. I'd like to get rid of that and let the browser do the CSS scaling again. (This alone doesn't work consistently now.) But I want my large images to remain sharp and not blurry. So I need a way to determine the pixel scale value to let the server return larger images than the size in virtual pixels.